# KeyCloak with Spring Boot and Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, azure-active-directory, keycloak

I'm working on a Spring Boot application, we'll be using Azure AD (Active Directory) for an oAuth 2.0 compliant approach, this is for both user auth into the UI and for communication with our internal services.

I also need to define and administer user roles.

I know I can use the plain Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory, however, I was wondering it if would make sense to use KeyCloak in this scenario? or is KeyCloak tailored for other type of situations?

The reason I have this question is because if Azure AD already handles users, why would one need KeyCloak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason I have this question is because if Azure AD already handles
> users, why would one need KeyCloak?

1. Global Rest API is bound with oAuth2.
2. Keycloak is used inside Spring Boot to authenticate and authorize users of our API.
3. Un-authenticated requests against this API is not possible.
4. To make sure that authentication/authorization component is absolutely reliable and tested, we have some key attributes within Keyclock.
5. KeyCloak is JWT based and authentication, authorization and sso is in one bundle.
6. KeyCloak can save much of your time.

**Here is some feature that KeyCloak Provide that makes differs from other Identity Providers.**

•   Single-Sign On: In this your application don’t have to deals with login forms once you logged-in to KeyCloak.users don't have to login again to access a different application and Same for logout.

•   Social Login: If you have user account in KeyCloak you can login to any social network with same account provided Federation is configured with the platform in KeyCloak.

•   User Federation: Keycloak has built-in support to connect to existing LDAP or Active Directory servers. You can also implement your own provider if you have users in other stores, such as a relational database.

•   It support the multiple authentication protocol like SAML 2.0,SAML2.2,Open ID connect and Oauth2.0 for integrating with various Identity provider added to this platform.

•   This can significantly reduce the User management efforts by integrating the users from Identity providers for our KeyCloak secured applications. [Example](https://www.alphabold.com/azure-ad-configuration/)

Please refer this [document](https://www.keycloak.org/about) to know the list of features provided by KeyCloack